# Rails and Model Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, model-validation

I want to put some model level validation on the following table:

```
create_table :audios do |t|
  t.integer :library_id, :null => false
  t.string :file, :null => false, :limit => 2048
  t.string :name, :limit => 512
  t.timestamps
end
```

Does this mean, that my model, which (so far) looks like:

```
class Audio < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :library
end
```

Has

```
class Audio < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :library
  ...
```

or

```
class Audio < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :library_id
  ...
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To validate the presence of an association, use its name, **without** `_id` appended:

```
validates_presence_of :library
```

It will validate two things:

1. `library_id` is present
2. a `Library` with the given `id` exists

Using `validates_presence_of :library_id` will only give you the first validation of the two.

In addition to this, the version without `_id` will also correctly validate if both records are new (and therefore `library_id` is still unset).